# Testing JavaScript in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cakephp, selenium, qunit

In my CakePHP project, I'd like to run unit-tests of my JavaScript codes for the views. I'm trying to use QUnit for testing JavaScript.

1. Is CakePHP's testing framework capable of integrating JavaScript tests?
2. Where should I put the test codes?
3. Is there any example or information for that?
4. Should I consider Selenium for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a php framework, what makes you think you can test another
   language with that?
2. I would not put them into webroot/js/test and disable access to that folder via .htaccess
   in the live environment
3. http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/
4. Yes, because it sounds you want to test that the whole rendered page works. I'm not sure what you exactly want to test.

Comment: The JavaScript codes are parts of the CakePHP project. I'd like to integrate all tests under a single framework, if possible.  Mainly I want to test JavaScript functions rather than UIs.